# Jira: How to repair HTTP 500/Exception on login after import?

Tags: jira

i'm working with an old Jira Version (6.3.1). Due to hardware limitations, before we are able to upgrade to a newer Jira version we have to migrate it to another server. The setup on the new server works, importing the data without any problems, too. But after successful import, login fails with the following Exception:

```
Jan 23, 2017 8:30:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:149)
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:112)
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference.get(ResettableLazyReference.java:92)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.UserOrGroupCache.getCache(UserOrGroupCache.java:57)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.UserOrGroupCache.getCaseInsensitive(UserOrGroupCache.java:77)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.OfBizGroupDao.findByNameOrNull(OfBizGroupDao.java:114)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.OfBizDelegatingMembershipDao.doGroupQuery(OfBizDelegatingMembershipDao.java:177)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.OfBizDelegatingMembershipDao.doNameQuery(OfBizDelegatingMembershipDao.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.OfBizDelegatingMembershipDao.result(OfBizDelegatingMembershipDao.java:154)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.OfBizDelegatingMembershipDao.search(OfBizDelegatingMembershipDao.java:135)
        at com.atlassian.crowd.directory.AbstractInternalDirectory.searchGroupRelationships(AbstractInternalDirectory.java:949)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.JiraDirectoryManager.searchDirectGroupRelationships(JiraDirectoryManager.java:141)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.JiraDirectoryManager.searchNestedGroupRelationships(JiraDirectoryManager.java:281)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.JiraDirectoryManager.searchNestedGroupRelationships(JiraDirectoryManager.java:272)
        at com.atlassian.crowd.manager.application.ApplicationServiceGeneric.doNestedDirectoryMembershipQuery(ApplicationServiceGeneric.java:2116)
        at com.atlassian.crowd.manager.application.ApplicationServiceGeneric.searchNestedGroupRelationships(ApplicationServiceGeneric.java:1566)
        at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.CrowdServiceImpl.searchNestedGroupRelationships(CrowdServiceImpl.java:234)
        at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.CrowdServiceImpl.search(CrowdServiceImpl.java:158)
        at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.DelegatingCrowdService.search(DelegatingCrowdService.java:60)
        at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.FilteredCrowdServiceImpl.search(FilteredCrowdServiceImpl.java:143)
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.DefaultGlobalPermissionManager.hasPermission(DefaultGlobalPermissionManager.java:323)
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.DefaultGlobalPermissionManager.hasPermission(DefaultGlobalPermissionManager.java:298)
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.DefaultPermissionManager.hasPermission(DefaultPermissionManager.java:148)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor292.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.atlassian.util.profiling.object.ObjectProfiler.profiledInvoke(ObjectProfiler.java:83)
        at com.atlassian.jira.config.component.SwitchingInvocationHandler.invoke(SwitchingInvocationHandler.java:28)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.hasPermission(Unknown Source)
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.auth.AuthorisationManagerImpl.authoriseForLoginViaJIRA(AuthorisationManagerImpl.java:164)
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.auth.AuthorisationManagerImpl.authoriseForLogin(AuthorisationManagerImpl.java:127)
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.login.LoginManagerImpl.authoriseForLogin(LoginManagerImpl.java:145)
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraRoleMapper.canLogin(JiraRoleMapper.java:36)
        at com.atlassian.seraph.auth.DefaultAuthenticator.isAuthorised(DefaultAuthenticator.java:232)
        at com.atlassian.seraph.auth.DefaultAuthenticator.authoriseUserAndEstablishSession(DefaultAuthenticator.java:200)
        at com.atlassian.seraph.auth.DefaultAuthenticator.login(DefaultAuthenticator.java:105)
        at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.PasswordBasedLoginFilter.runAuthentication(PasswordBasedLoginFilter.java:132)
        at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.PasswordBasedLoginFilter.login(PasswordBasedLoginFilter.java:77)
        at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:134)
        at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLoginFilter.doFilter(JiraLoginFilter.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
        at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:79)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
        at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:40)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
        at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.johnson.filters.AbstractJohnsonFilter.doFilter(AbstractJohnsonFilter.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:88)
        at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:59)
        at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.gzip.JiraGzipFilter.doFilter(JiraGzipFilter.java:55)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
        at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.JiraAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(JiraAnalyticsFilter.java:40)
        at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
        at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.core.filters.cache.AbstractCachingFilter.doFilter(AbstractCachingFilter.java:33)
        at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.core.filters.encoding.AbstractEncodingFilter.doFilter(AbstractEncodingFilter.java:41)
        at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
        at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.PathMatchingEncodingFilter.doFilter(PathMatchingEncodingFilter.java:45)
        at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.jira.startup.JiraStartupChecklistFilter.doFilter(JiraStartupChecklistFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.doFilter(MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.java:41)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:87)
        at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraFirstFilter.doFilter(JiraFirstFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.DirectoryEntityKey.hashCode(DirectoryEntityKey.java:74)
        at com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Equals.doHash(Equivalences.java:91)
        at com.google.common.base.Equivalence.hash(Equivalence.java:105)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.hash(LocalCache.java:1888)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getIfPresent(LocalCache.java:3958)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.getIfPresent(LocalCache.java:4763)
        at com.atlassian.cache.memory.DelegatingCache.get(DelegatingCache.java:95)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.UserOrGroupCache$PutIfAbsentVisitor.visit(UserOrGroupCache.java:315)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.UserOrGroupCache$PutIfAbsentVisitor.visit(UserOrGroupCache.java:302)
        at com.atlassian.jira.util.Functions$MappedVisitor.visit(Functions.java:218)
        at com.atlassian.jira.entity.SelectQueryImpl$ExecutionContextImpl$4.consume(SelectQueryImpl.java:258)
        at com.atlassian.jira.entity.SelectQueryImpl$ExecutionContextImpl.consumeWith(SelectQueryImpl.java:240)
        at com.atlassian.jira.entity.SelectQueryImpl$ExecutionContextImpl.visitWith(SelectQueryImpl.java:253)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.OfBizGroupDao$GroupCache.visitAllUsingDatabase(OfBizGroupDao.java:438)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.UserOrGroupCache.buildCacheIfRequiredUnderLock(UserOrGroupCache.java:170)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.UserOrGroupCache.buildCacheIfRequired(UserOrGroupCache.java:140)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.UserOrGroupCache$1.create(UserOrGroupCache.java:47)
        at com.atlassian.jira.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.UserOrGroupCache$1.create(UserOrGroupCache.java:42)
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference$InternalReference.create(ResettableLazyReference.java:182)
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$Sync.run(LazyReference.java:325)
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:143)
        ... 124 more
```

- Any idea what's the reason for this behaviour?
- Any idea what "ofbiz" is?

Best regards
Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've got a reply from the Atlassian Support:

> Based on the error message above, this could be due to there is an empty string value in one of the cwd_group.group_name table. Oracle specifically treats empty string as 'null' value that causes UserOrGroupCache constantly throwing java.lang.NullPointerException. This also explains the problem is not reproducible in Postgres database.

There was a group with an empty group name, renaming it fixed this error.